# Python: Numpy percentile confusing results

Tags: python, numpy

When using the Python Numpy to calculate quantile/percentile, the results are a little bit weird as below. I am quite confused about this, could anyone explain why?

```py
import numpy as np

x = range(1,1031)
x = np.array(x)

np.percentile(x,1,interpolation='lower')
# 11
np.percentile(x,1,interpolation='higher')
# 12

np.percentile(x,0.972,interpolation='lower')
# 11
np.percentile(x,0.972,interpolation='higher')
# 12

np.percentile(x,0.971,interpolation='lower')
# 10
np.percentile(x,0.971,interpolation='higher')
# 11
```

I expect the lower and higher 1% quantiles of the numbers from 1 to 1030 to be 10 and 11, but the actual results are 11 and 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine, for a while, that your array were `x = range(1,1002)` (i.e. 1 to 1001, inclusive). Then 1 is the 0% percentile, and 1001 is 100%. The median would be 501, and it should be the 50% percentile. From this pattern, you can probably interpolate to get that p% percentile should be 10p+1. In particular, the 1% percentile should be 11.

Now, since your actual array is `range(1,1031)`, shouldn't the 1% percentile be slightly higher?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks!